# How can I attach a header to a datagram in c++ for networking?

Tags: c++11, network-programming

I have a 
`struct ip ipHeader;`

that I want to attach in front of the actual data, which is
`string data;`

so that I can send it in one packet via the `send` function, which takes in a char* buffer. How would I go about trying to concatenate these? I need to attach this ipHeader because it's a custom header that's different from the UDP header that's automatically attached when sending messages.

edit* A clarification is that I need to attach this header along with the UDP header that's attached when sending. Hence, SOCK_RAW is not necessarily what I need/want.

Comment: If you want to supply the header yourself, you'll probably have to work with raw sockets using the SOCK_RAW option when creating the socket.

Comment: @o_weisman I'm sending it via UDP so i don't need SOCK_RAW, but I need to attach this header along with the header that UDP will attach for some other information I need.

Comment: You are trying to send a datagram with your own IP header are you not? Example here: http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html.  A UDP header always follows the IP header that's why it's called UDP/IP

Comment: @o_weisman You can treat it like a virtual IP header. It's a school project, and we are dealing with virtual IPs, so these ip headers are more like simulation data. However, I still need to send it under one packet together with the string data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send two pieces of data as a single packet, you have two main choices:

1. Copy them both into a new buffer, and send that.
2. Use `writev()` (`WSASend()` on Windows).

The second approach is appealing because it seems to be designed for exactly what you're doing: sending two (or more) buffers at once.  But in my own testing, it was not actually faster (on Linux) than the first approach.

The fastest and simplest solution is often to simply embed the header in your data from the start.  So whenever you allocate a message, add space for the header at the start.  You can then use "placement new" to invoke the header constructor if there is one, or simply assign its fields.